# Trouble with differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

I tried to solve this differential equation:

$$\epsilon y''(x)+xy'(x)=-\epsilon \pi^2 \cos(\pi x)-\pi x\sin(\pi x)$$

with boundary conditions: $y(-1)=-2, \space y(1)=0$. If we take $\epsilon=0.1$, Mathematica can solve it without any trouble

```
Block[{e = 0.1, min = -1, max = 1},
 Plot[Evaluate[
   y[x] /. NDSolve[{e y''[x] + 
        y'[x] x == -e Pi^2 Cos[Pi x] - Pi x Sin[Pi x], 
      y[min] == -2, y[max] == 0}, y, {x, min, max}]], {x, min, max}]
 ]
```

[image]

But if we want a smaller $\epsilon$, let say 0.01, Mathematica seems unable to handle it. Is there any options to invoke or methods to employ to get the desired result? Anyway, this is the solution for $\epsilon=0.0001$.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Piece of advice: don't use `Block` to inject values into parameters. Use `With` instead.

Comment: The fundamental problem would appear to be that, in the limit of small `e`, the order of the equation drops from second to first, with the result that there is one too many boundary conditions.

Answer (score 12):

`DSolve` can handle this.

```
Clear[y];
y[x_, e_] = y[x] /. DSolve[{
      e y''[x] + y'[x] x == -e Pi^2 Cos[Pi x] - Pi x Sin[Pi x],
      y[-1] == -2, y[1] == 0}, y[x], x][[1]] // Simplify
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[y[x, e], {x, -1, 1}],
 {{e, 0.01}, 0.0001, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm looking for numerical solution.

Comment: @Deco Bob's symbolic solution can be evaluated numerically quickly, and with better accuracy than a mere numerical approximation.  In fact `DSolve` can solve the problem in full generality: `DSolve[{e y''[x] + y'[x] x == -e Pi^2 Cos[Pi x] - Pi x Sin[Pi x], y[min] == -2, y[max] == 0}, y, x]`.  Is there some reason you do not think this is a superior solution?

Answer (score 10):

As noted by @bbgodfrey, the "shooting" algorithms that Mathematica tends to use are not well-adapted to this particular equation.  Better would be some kind of relaxation method, which is what Mathematica uses (I think) for solving PDEs on a mesh.  And an ODE is just a PDE in one dimension, so let's try solving this equation on a one-dimensional mesh:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"] 
truey[x_,e_] = Cos[\[Pi] x] + Erf[x/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[e])]/Erf[1/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[e])];

e = 0.0001; min = -1; max = 1;
mesh = ToElementMesh[Interval[{min, max}], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.05];
bcs = {DirichletCondition[y[x] == -2, x == min], DirichletCondition[y[x] == 0, x == max]}
soln = NDSolve[{e y''[x] + y'[x] x == -e Pi^2 Cos[Pi x] - Pi x Sin[Pi x], bcs}, y, Element[x, mesh]]
Plot[{Evaluate[y[x] /. soln], truey[x, e]}, {x, min, max}]
Clear[e, min, max]
```

[image]

I've plotted here the result from Mathematica's finite element solver (in blue) versus the true solution found by @BobHanlon (in yellow).  I've actually used a coarser mesh than is ideal to show the difference between the two;  if you set `MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01` in the above code (instead of 0.05), the two curves are indistinguishable at this resolution.

Answer (score 8):

To see why NDSolve has difficulty with this problem for very small `e`, consider that `NDSolve` solves this two-point boundary value problem by some form of shooting.  In other words, it varies `y'[min]` until one is found that yields the desired `y[max]`.  However, as `e` becomes very small, the sensitivity of `y[max]` to `y'[min]` becomes great, because the differential equation becomes singular in that limit.

```
y''[x] + y'[x] x/e == -Pi^2 Cos[Pi x] - Pi x Sin[Pi x]/e
```

This is also apparent from Bob Hanlon's symbolic solution.  To illustrate the sensitivity of `y[max]` to `y'[min]`, consider

```
slope = D[Cos[π x] + Erf[x/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[e])]/Erf[1/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[e])],  x] /. x -> -1;
LogLogPlot[N[slope], {e, 0.0001, .1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

You can work around this sensitivity by increasing `WorkingPrecision`, e. g. for `e = .01`,

```
With[{e = 1/100, min = -1, max = 1}, 
    Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. NDSolve[{e y''[x] + y'[x] x == -e Pi^2 Cos[Pi x] - 
      Pi x Sin[Pi x], y[min] == -2, y[max] == 0}, y, {x, min, max}, 
      WorkingPrecision -> 50, MaxSteps -> 50000]], {x, min, max}]]
```

[image]

but doing so rapidly becomes prohibitively expensive as `e` is further reduced.