# Solve stiff system by shooting method

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, special-functions, parametric-functions, nonlinear

I'm trying to solve a second order differential equation with the shooting method but, it appears to be a stiff system. This is worst for a larger parameter $\mu$. I've tried different methods: `StiffnessSwitching`, `LSODA`, `BDF` also, changing `MaxStepFraction` and `WorkingPrecision` options. None of these has helped. An example of the code is:

```
P[r_, rv_] := -(r^2/16) (1 - Sqrt[(rv/r)^3 + 1] + 3/2 (rv/r)^3 
Hypergeometric2F1[1/3, 1/2, 4/3, -(rv/r)^3])
nonintphi :=  Block[{r0 = 0.01, g = 1, λ = 1, μ = 3, σ =
10^2, rv = (4/π σ)^(1/3), inf = 10 rv}, 
ParametricNDSolve[{1/r^2 D[r^2 Φ'[r], r] - λ Φ[r]^3 
+ (μ^2 - g (P[r, rv])^2) Φ[r] ==  0, 
Φ[r0] == 0, Φ'[r0] == B}, Φ, {r, r0, inf}, B, 
Method -> {"LSODA"}, MaxStepFraction -> 1/100000, WorkingPrecision -> 30,
MaxSteps -> Infinity]]

Block[{r0 = 0.01, g = 1, λ = 1, μ = 3, σ = 10^2, 
rv = (4/π σ)^(1/3), inf = 10 rv}, 
bcs = FindRoot[Φ[B][inf] == 
Sqrt[(μ^2 - g (P[inf, rv])^2)/λ] /. nonintphi, {B, 0}, AccuracyGoal -> 3, 
PrecisionGoal -> 4]];
```

The problem arises when using `FindRoot` and gives something like:

> At r == 3.5998792500342004380773953162236682802682889219723012678651`\
>   30., step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system \
>   suspected.

Same thing happens if I use `NDSolve` with `Method->"Shooting Method"`.
At the end, I want to use the value $\mu=10^{24}$, so this problem becomes even worse. How can I get the integration to work?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: May I ask where your DE came from?

Comment: Please reduce your code to remove extraneous issues such as the use of `FindRoot` and `P` and condense it into a self-contained example focused on the integral you having problems with.

Comment: Note that it's also possible to use finite element methods to solve ODEs;  see my [previous answer here.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86851/27813)  In particular, this is an independent method from the shooting method, and can be better at dealing with certain boundary value problems than the shooting method is.

Comment: @Michael Seifert Nonlinear coefficients are not supported in NDSolve, Mathematica 10.2

Comment: @Willinski:  Thanks for the note;  I forgot about that issue.  Since this differential equation has a `Φ^3` term, it wouldn't work.

Comment: The DE is the equation of motion for a field.

The FindRoot part is the most important one since it's where I find the errors and I need it to solve the equation by shooting method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The goal of this question, I believe, is selecting `Φ[r0]` so that the solution connects smoothly to the asymptotic solution at large `r`.  As will become apparent, large is about `3`.  Begin be rewriting the code as

```
r0 = 0.01; g = 1; λ = 1; μ = 3; σ = 10^2; rv = (4/π σ)^(1/3); inf = 5;
p = -(r^2/16) (1 - Sqrt[(rv/r)^3 + 1] + 
            3/2 (rv/r)^3 Hypergeometric2F1[1/3, 1/2, 4/3, -(rv/r)^3]);
s1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{1/r^2 D[r^2 Φ'[r], r] + (μ^2 - g p^2 - λ Φ[r]^2) Φ[r] == 0, 
    Φ[r0] == b, Φ'[r0] == 0}, Φ, {r, r0, inf}, {b}, WorkingPrecision -> 30];
```

From the ODE, it is clear that the asymptotic solution is given by

```
(μ^2 - g p^2 - λ Φ[r]^2) == 0
```

Now, by trial and error I have found that `b = .055035287243` is the desired parameter value.  Clearly, this value can be obtained using `NDSolve` with `Method -> "Shooting"`, but it is late and I am tired.

```
Plot[{s1[.055035287243][r], Sqrt[(μ^2 - g p^2)]}, {r, r0, inf}, 
    PlotRange -> {-3, 3}, AxesLabel -> {r, Φ}]
```

[image]

Here, the blue curve is from `ParametricNDSolve`, and the orange is the asymptotic solution,

```
Φa = Sqrt[(μ^2 - g p^2)]
```

They are indistinguishable to the eye for `r > 2.6`.  A numerical comparison of the two at `r -> inf` is quite good.

```
{s1[.055035287243][r], Sqrt[(μ^2 - g p^2)] // N} /. r -> inf
(* {2.58994, 2.59165} *)
```

**Addendum**

[Willinski](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/31001/willinski) is correct (+1) that I interchanged the `Φ[r0]` and `Φ'[r0]` boundary conditions last night.  However, my inadvertent error has one advantage: It produces a solution well behaved as `r` approaches `0`.

```
r0 = 10^-10; 
s3 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{1/r^2 D[r^2 Φ'[r], r] + (μ^2 - g p^2 - λ Φ[r]^2) Φ[r] == 0, 
    Φ[r0] == b, Φ'[r0] == 0}, Φ, {r, r0, inf}, {b}, WorkingPrecision -> 30];
Plot[{s3[.054949][r], Sqrt[(μ^2 - g p^2)]}, {r, r0, inf}, 
    AxesLabel -> {r, Φ}]
```

which produces a plot indistinguishable to the eye from my plot above but extends down to `r0 = 10^-10`.

Incidentally, why the problem is ill-behaved at large `r` can be seen by linearizing the ODE about the asymptotic solution, `Φa`, defined above.  One finds after a small amount of algebra that small errors in `Φ - Φa` grow exponentially at a rate `Sqrt[2] Φa`, or about `10^9` over a distance of `5`.

**Automating "Trial and Error"**

The OP understandably would prefer a better way than trial and error to find the parameter, here named `b0`, that yields the desired curve.  Using `FindRoot` on `s3[b][inf]` is unreliable, because the integration does not reach `r = inf` for `b` much larger than `b0`.  Below is a plot of the value of `r` at which the integration stops, as a function of `b`, with `b0` superimposed.

```
Plot[Quiet@s3[b]["Domain"][[1, 2]], {b, .054, .056}, AxesLabel -> {b, r}, 
   Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{0.0549492, inf}]}]
```

[image]

with `s3` calculated without `WorkingPrecison -> 30`, because doing so is much faster and does not change the curve.  Interestingly, `Method -> StiffnessSwitching` also does not change the curve.  Strictly speaking, the ODE is not [stiff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation); it is an unstable separatrix.

So, to use `FindRoot`, we need to operate in the flat portion of the curve above, which in turn means finding the point at which it no longer is flat.  Searching for that point by successive bifurcations seems to work well.

```
bl = 0; bu = .1;
Do[bt = (bl + bu)/2; If[Quiet@s3[bt]["Domain"][[1, 2]] < inf, bu = bt, bl = bt], {i, 20}]
FindRoot[s3[b][inf] == Sqrt[(μ^2 - g p^2)] /. r -> inf, {b, 0, bl}]
(* {b -> 0.0549492} *)
```

as desired.

**inf = 10**

At the request of the OP, here are the corresponding results for `inf = 10`.  With `s3` computed with `WorkingPrecision -> 30`,

```
inf = 10; bl = 0; bu = .1;
Do[bt = (bl + bu)/2; If[Quiet@s3[bt]["Domain"][[1, 2]] < inf, bu = bt, bl = bt], {i, 50}]
NumberForm[{bl, Quiet@s3[bl]["Domain"][[1, 2]], bu, Quiet@s3[bu]["Domain"][[1, 2]]}, 15]
(* {0.0549492117281679, 10.000000000000, 0.0549492117281679, 9.99998284445001} *)

b0 = b /. FindRoot[s3[b][inf] == Sqrt[(μ^2 - g p^2)] /. r -> inf, {b, 5/100, bl},
    WorkingPrecision -> 30];
NumberForm[b0, 18]
(* 0.0549492117275881041 *)

Plot[Quiet@s3[b]["Domain"][[1, 2]], {b, .054, .056}, AxesLabel -> {b, r}, 
    Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{b0, inf}]}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{s3[b0][r], Sqrt[(μ^2 - g p^2)]}, {r, r0, inf}, AxesLabel -> {r, Φ}]
```

[image]

Further increasing `inf` will require even larger `WorkingPrecision`.

**Asymptotic Series Solution**

A slightly better solution can be obtained for large `r` by expanding the ODE as a power series in `1/r`.

```
n = 20; app = Sum[a[i] r^-i, {i, 0, n}];
Unevaluated[1/r^2 D[r^2 D[Φ[r], r], r] + (μ^2 - g p^2 - λ Φ[r]^2) Φ[r]] /. Φ[r] -> app;
CoefficientList[Series[%, {r, Infinity, n}] // Normal, 1/r];
exp = app /. Solve[Thread[% == 0], Array[a[# - 1] &, n + 1]][[3]];

N[exp]
(* 3. -10.5543/r^2 -19.7382/r^4 + 167.977/r^5 - 86.7254/r^6 + 777.599/r^7 ... *)
```

The value of `b` for which the numerical solution smoothly matches to this series is computed as before, with the result here called `b1`.

```
b1 = b /. FindRoot[s3[b][inf] == exp /. r -> inf, {b, 5/100, bl}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 30];
NumberForm[b1, 18]
(* 0.0549492117275880915 *)
```

which differs only slightly from `b0` computed above.  The plot of `s3[b1]` is, of course, indistinguishable to the eye from the plot above.  Nonetheless, the series `exp` agrees more closely with `s3[b1]` than `Sqrt[(μ^2 - g p^2)]` does.

```
err = -exp[[2]]; 
LogPlot[{Sqrt[(μ^2 - g p^2)] - s3[b1][r], -exp + s3[b1][r], err}, {r, r0, 10}, 
    AxesLabel -> {r, ΔΦ}, PlotRange -> {{3, 10}, {10^-10, 1}}]
```

[image]

(The green curve is the upper bound on the error of the series expansion, obtained by noting that the series is alternating after the first few terms.)  Thus, the series solution is far more accurate at larger `r`, where it converges well.  Nonetheless, `Φa = Sqrt[(μ^2 - g p^2)]` is a reasonable approximation over a broad range.

A series solution for small `r` also can be derived.

```
n = 14; app = c + Sum[a[i] r^i, {i, 2, n + 2, 1/2}];
Unevaluated[1/r^2 D[r^2 D[Φ[r], r], r] + (μ^2 - g p^2 - λ Φ[r]^2) Φ[r]] /. Φ[r] -> app;
CoefficientList[Simplify[(Assuming[r >= 0, Series[%, {r, 0, n}]] // Normal) 
    /. r -> z^2, z > 0], z];
exp0 = (app /. Solve[Thread[% == 0], Array[a[(# + 3)/2] &, 2 n + 1]])[[1]];
```

From  it, we find that the solution is indeed free of singularities at `r = 0`, provided that `Φ'[0] == 0`.  Unfortunately, the series does not converge well for `r > 1`.  Hence, it is not practical to link this series with the asymptotic series to obtain a complete analytical solution to the ODE.  (I had hoped to do so, when I began deriving these series.)

Comment: It's a fine work! (+1) :)

Comment: I think that the asymptotic form is wrong since the second derivative still survives when r goes to 0. So the asymptotic is Φ''[r]+(μ^2 - g p^2 - λ Φ[r]^2) == 0, but form the plots it seems that the second derivative becomes small so your asymptotics look ok.
Also, the problem in this ode arises when I try to shoot to Sqrt[(μ^2 - g (P^2)/λ]. So, when I run the code using the Findroot it gives the error:
At r == 3.5998792500342004380773953162236682802682889219723012678651`30., step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>

Comment: The issue is that I want an efficient way to find this b, not just trial and error because later I will change the parameters \mu \lambda g and \sigma.

Comment: @marRrR  I have added code to automate finding the desired parameter value.  It includes a procedure for selecting the range of parameters for which `FindRoot` works well.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, this automated way seems really useful. The only thing I'm worried of is that the initial value b needed to shoot to the desired boundary condition at inf is encountered after the flat line, which I think it's the case for the values \mu=10^24 and \sigma=10^38.
I haven't had the time to confirm these but seems like it would be the case. How could I overcome these?

Comment: @marRrR  No, I do not think so.

Comment: It doesn't if you keep inf=5 but if you use inf = 10 rv as I had it (and as I need) then :
Quiet@s3[10^-10]["Domain"][[1, 2]] 
gives
1.00000000000000000000000000000*10^-10

Comment: Also, you may have a typo in the code where you do the biffurcations since inside the Do[] you have bu = bt, bl = bt

Comment: @marRrR The code is as intended.  I shall run a few more numbers tonight.  It appears that `b0` lies very close to the edge of the flat region as `inf` is increased.

Comment: @marRrR  For `inf = 10`, the edge of the plateau is `bl = bu = 0.05494921172816784`, and `b0 = 0.0549492117275881`.  I needed `WorkingPrecision -> 30` to obtain these values.

Comment: Thanks fo all the help and sorry for keep on bothering but the value I need is inf = 10*rv  when sigma=10^38 which makes inf=5*10^13, but I'll keep trying with your method by myself. It just seems that the working precision required would be too big.

Comment: Just another small thing, it seems that you kept the boundary conditions Φ[r0] and Φ'[r0] interchanged which might be making differ the results you get with what I get.

Comment: @marRrR  Very near `r = 0`, the solutions to your ODE are Modified Spherical Bessel Functions.  Choosing `Φ'[r0] == 0`, as I do, selects the nonsingular solution.   If you want your solution to behave smoothly very near `r = 0`, use my boundary conditions there.  For your `σ = 10^38` case, are `g` and `μ` unchanged?  It might be possible to make some progress by rescaling `r` by `rv`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30640/discussion-between-marrrr-and-bbgodfrey).

Comment: @marRrR  After I sent the following message on chat, it occurred to me that you might not be able to use the chat room because you have less than 20 points.  "I was unable to join you in the chat room when you first invited me to do so. Sorry. I have derived and added to my answer a power series expansion of the large r solution, which should be quite adequate for obtaining results at 10 rv. You really only need to solve the ODE numerically for smaller r, roughly r < 5 for the parameters in your question. Trying to solve the ODE to 10 rv is not practical, I believe."

Answer (score 3):

I have Phi'[r0] selected, as did the OP. The value of b was determined empirically.

```
r0 = 1/100; g = 1; λ = 1; μ = 3; σ = 10^2; rv = (4/π σ)^(1/3); inf = 10 rv;
(*stiff system, reduced inf -> 8*) 

p = -(r^2/16) (1 - Sqrt[(rv/r)^3 + 1] + 3/2 (rv/r)^3 Hypergeometric2F1[1/3, 1/2, 4/3, -(rv/r)^3]);

s1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[
{1/r^2 D[r^2 Φ'[r], r] + (μ^2 -g p^2 - λ Φ[r]^2) Φ[r] == 0,
     Φ[r0] == 0, Φ'[r0] == b}, Φ, {r, r0, 8}, {b}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]

Plot[{s1[#][r], Sqrt[(μ^2 - g p^2)]}, {r, r0, 8}, PlotRange -> All] & /@ {5, 5.77533449, 5.7753345}
```

[image]

Check the solution:

```
s2 = NDSolveValue[
{1/r^2 D[r^2 Φ'[r],r] + (μ^2 -g p^2 - λ Φ[r]^2) Φ[r] == 0, 
Φ[r0] == 0, Φ'[r0] == 5.77533449`30}, Φ, {r, r0, 8}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]

Plot[{s2[r], Sqrt[(μ^2 - g p^2)]}, {r, r0, 8}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
s2[r0]
0.*10^-31

s2'[r0]
5.77533449000000000000
```

Comment: This indeed gives a solution, but you found the value of b empirically. At the end, the equation I need to solve is for \mu=10^24 and finding the value by trial and error is not efficient so I would like to do it with FindRoot.

Comment: @marRrR Many things in the world were determined empirically! It will remain you probably nothing to solve the system. You know, your system with the given values is very stiff and singular, dependent of b. There is a lot of work to find a solution at all. Look at the above plots, the system already responds to the 7th decimal place!

Comment: If I just try to solve it empirically for my value for \mu=10^24 and \sigma=10^38 whenever I try to plot or get the value at inf for a given b it gives the stiff system error.

Comment: @marRrR It seems that you need to work on your DE system. With your mu and sigma try out `Table[{Sqrt[(\[Mu]^2 - g p^2)]}, {r, r0, 1, 0.1}]`.

Comment: I know that (\[Mu]^2 - g p^2) becomes negative in that region, that's the behaviour I'm searching for.