# Trouble with shooting method for a 4th-order stiff ODE

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, boundary-condition-at-infinity

The ODE I need to solve is

$$\left(y^3y^{\prime\prime\prime}\right)^\prime+\frac{5}{8}xy^\prime-\frac{1}{2}y+\frac{c}{y}=0$$
where $\prime$ denotes differentiation, $c$ is a constant and $0<c\le1$.
It needs **4** boundary conditions (BCs): $y^\prime(0)=y^{\prime\prime\prime}(0)=0$ are given, and the other two values of $y(0)$ and
$y^{\prime\prime}(0)$ are determined by shooting for BCs at infinity (or $x_\text{Max}$).

Inspired by @ bbgodfrey's idea in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97499/36545), I know that the far-field asymptotic behavior is given by `DSolve`ing the remainder of the ODE after the nonlinear derivative term are neglected:

```
DSolve[5/8 x y'[x] - 1/2 y[x] + c/y[x] == 0, y[x], x]
```

Thus the far-field asymptotic behavior is $y= kx^{4/5}$, where $k$ is a constant. Accordingly, we refer to a solution with $y\sim x^{4/5}$ asymptotic behavior as a $x^{4/5}$ solution. Here, I want to search for this kind of solutions by shooting method in which the ODE is integrated from $x_0=0$ to some large value of $x_\text{Max}$, say $x_\text{Max}=10$.

The shooting parameters $y(0)$ and $y^{\prime\prime}(0)$ will be adjusted so that
$y-\frac{5}{4}xy^\prime=0$ or $y+\frac{25}{4}x^2y^{\prime\prime}=0$ at $x=x_\text{Max}$ is satisfied. The two BCs were chosen to be independent to involve low-order derivatives and to require $y\propto x^{4/5}$ at the end of the integration interval.

Thanks to @ xzczd's answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103616/trouble-with-shooting-method-for-a-4th-order-differential-equation), an example of the code is:

```
c = 1;
(*c=1/10;*)
ode = D[y[x]^3*y'''[x], x] + 5/8 x y'[x] - 1/2 y[x] + c/y[x] == 0;
bc1 = y[x] - 5/4 x y'[x] == 0;
bc2 = y[x] + 25/4 x^2 y''[x] == 0;
```

Thank again to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25363/solving-an-ode-in-power-series/96696#96696), I can obtain the series solution at $x_0=0$ with `seriesDSolve`

```
solSeries = seriesDSolve[ode, y, {x, 0, 5}, 
                        {y[0] -> a, y'[0] -> 0, y''[0] -> b, y'''[0] -> 0}]
```

We thus obtain a set of boundary conditions at $x=x_0$ by

```
newbclist =  Thread[(Derivative[#][y][x0] == 
             (D[Normal@solSeries, {x, #}] /. x -> x0) &) /@ Range[0, 3]]
```

Then, give the interval, solve the ODE and plot the parameter plane

```
x0 = 0; xMax = 6;
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{ode, newbclist}, y, {x, x0, xMax}, {a, b}]
ContourPlot[{bc1, bc2} /. x -> xMax /. y -> sol[a, b] // Evaluate, 
{a, 0.2, 0.6}, {b, -0.05, 1}]
```

Unfortunately, Mathematica gives something like this:

> ParametricNDSolveValue::ndsz: At x$803007 == 0.27144285125721357`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

as encounters in [this problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97492/solve-stiff-system-by-shooting-method/97499#97499).

After some experiments, I found the situation appears to be worse for a larger parameter $c$, i.e. $c\rightarrow 1$. And I also played with the intervals of $a$ and $b$ but it seems no help. 
Three ugly results for your reference (sorry!...)

**1.** When I use `c = 1/10`, `xMax = 0.5` with `{a, -0.2, 1}, {b, -0.1, 1}`, `ContourPlot` gives

[image]

**2.** When I use `c = 1/10`, `xMax = 0.5` with `{a, 0.2, 0.6}, {b, -0.05, 1}`, `ContourPlot` gives

[image]

**3.** When I change to `bc1 = 1/2 y[x] - 5/8 x y'[x] - c/y[x] == 0;` with `c = 1`, `xMax = 6` and `{a, -0.2, 1}, {b, -0.1, 1}`, `ContourPlot` gives

[image]

**To sum up, my questions are:**

(1) After I find the parameter $y(0)$ and $y^{\prime\prime}(0)$, how can I figure out the associated constant $k$ in the far-field asymptotic behavior $y= kx^{4/5}$?

(2) Is it possible to estimate the parameters $y(0)$ and
$y^{\prime\prime}(0)$ automatically to start the integration, as shown in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97499/36545)?

Comment: I think it's just the nature of your equation: Some choices of `{a, b}` can't lead to a solution extending to infinity. Just observe this: `mid = sol[0.6, 0.6];
{{lb, rb}} = mid["Domain"]; Plot[mid[t], {t, lb, rb}, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: Thanks, @ xzczd, That really is the question. I am wondering is there any technique to find out the ranges of $a$ and $b$ so that the solutions can shoot up to an appropriate $x_\text{Max}$. In other words, I just try to explore the existence of some isolated parameter pairs of $(a,b)$ for certain given $c$ and $x_\text{Max}$. That is, the values of $y(0)$ and $y''(0)$ are determined by shooting for boundary condition at  $x_\text{Max}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatically looking for proper $y(0)$ and $y''(0)$ isn't easy, at least I can't think out a solution, still, I don't think you need such fascinating technique to solve the new equation, you just need to slightly modify the code for plotting to filter out those improper $(a,b)$:

```
Quiet@ContourPlot[
  If[y["Domain"][[1, -1]] < xMax, 1, #] == 0 & /@ Subtract @@@ {bc1, bc2} /. 
     x -> xMax /. y -> sol[a, b] // Evaluate, {a, 1, 1.6}, {b, -0.1, 0.2}, 
  PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

The plot range is obtained through not too much trial and error.

"How can I figure out the associated constant $k$ in the far-field asymptotic behavior $y=kx^{4/5}$?" Just use the obtained $a$ as b.c. of the far-field asymptotic equation.

"I tried the following direct shooting method… It gives some errors… " I guess it's because `bc1` and `bc2` are not b.c in usual meaning, after all, they're equal to

```
y[xMax] == (y[xMax] /. DSolve[#, y, x]) & /@ {bc1, bc2}
(* {y[6] == {E^(4/5) C[1]}, y[6] == {C[1] Cos[2/5] + C[2] Sin[2/5]}} *)
```

Comment: @ xzczd, I just noticed your reply. I will learn something from you and reply you later. Many thanks!

Comment: @ xzczd, 3 questions, I'm a beginner. 1. Do you remember what value of the $c$ and $xMax$ were used in your answer? 2. I found that you have `Map` a pure function `If[y["Domain"][[1, -1]] < xMax, 1, #] == 0 &` to each element in the 1st level of `Subtract @@@ {bc1, bc2}`. However, applying `Subtract` to `{bc1,bc2}` by `@@@` is just equivalent to `{bc1,bc2}`, if I didn't make a mistake on the computation sequence? That is, you apply _True_ or _False_ to `{bc1,bc2}`? 3. What is the meaning of `#` in `If` expression, I know it is commonly used the formal para. for a pure function. Thanks again!

Comment: @W.Robin 1. `c = 1; xMax = 6;` 2. Observe `Subtract @@@ {xx == yy, zz == ww}` 3. Yeah, `#` owns no other meaning, it's the argument of pure function. If you still have trouble in understanding its usage here, just execute `If[y["Domain"][[1, -1]] < xMax, 1, #] == 0 & /@ Subtract @@@ {bc1, bc2}` outside of `ContourPlot` and observe the result.

Comment: @ xzczd, now I understand a little bit: using `Subtract @@@ {bc1, bc2}` just extract the LHS of each BC. because the 1st level of `bc1` or `bc2` is just `Equal` in which the 2nd argument is 0! Am I right?

Comment: @W.Robin You got it :)

Comment: Hi, mysterious man @ xzczd, Thanks! I just don't know how many tricks I need to know! If I remove `Quiet@`, only one kind of warning occur (no longer stiff sys. detected): >...longer than depth of object. Now, I'm afraid of the correctness not only the precision of the resulting shooting parameters, which should be the intersections of these curves.

Comment: @W.Robin The warning isn't a big deal, it's simply because when `y["Domain"][[1, -1]]` execute for the first time, `y["Domain"]` isn't yet a list, in v10 a new function [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed.html) is introduced to handle this problem more properly, but since I (and you) are still in v9, so I simply used `Quiet`. This doesn't influence the result at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34426/discussion-between-w-robin-and-xzczd).

Comment: @ xzczd, I noticed that when I run your 'ContourPlot' code in the absence of `Quiet@` with `{bc1, bc2}` or {bc3}, the stiff issue appears again. So may I think the stiff or singularity issue is not resolved. Could you check my update in the Addendum 2? Thanks!

Comment: @W.Robin …No, it's resolved, the improper $(a,b)$ will be filter out after the warning appears. If you still have difficulty in understanding it, try this: `With[{a = 0.6, b = 0.6}, 
 If[y["Domain"][[1, -1]] < xMax, 1, #] == 0 & /@ Subtract @@@ {bc1, bc2} /. x -> xMax /. 
  y -> sol[a, b]]` .  BTW, `bc1` and `bc2` will also lead to `ParametricNDSolveValue::ndsz`

Comment: @ xzczd, thanks. Actually, the _True_ value `1` in the `If` conditional statement can be changed to any other value except for $0$. Am I right?

Comment: @W.Robin You got it :)

Comment: @xzczd  I have been struggling with similar but [different question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/173563/stiff-bvp-of-nonlinear-ode-alternative-enhancement-to-shooting-method). Could you take a look? Thanks!