# Using NIntegrate in Finite Difference Derivative method

Tags: numerical-integration, difference-equations, finite-difference-method

I'm trying to solve a second order differential equation using the code given by @xzczd [`here`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/174044/58649) which is based on [`this`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997).

What this code makes is transform differential equations in algebraic ones by means of the Finite Difference method.

When I solve the equation

```
    R*X''[R] - X'[R] + R^3 == 0;
```

I have no problems at all. However when I change the equation to

```
R*X''[R] - X'[R] + R^3*nColdr[R] == 0;
```

being that

```
nColdr[R_?NumberQ]=NIntegrate[g[x],{x,0,R}],
```

where g is a complicated function of x, I get the output:

```
FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {0. +2.09232*10^17 (-1.37456*10^-14+2.7573*10^-14 nColdr$6323491[{0.,0.20202,0.40404,0.606061,0.808081,1.0101,1.21212,1.41414,1.61616,1.81818,2.0202,2.22222,2.42424,<<26>>,7.87879,8.08081,8.28283,8.48485,8.68687,8.88889,9.09091,9.29293,9.49495,9.69697,9.89899,<<50>>}]),<<49>>,<<150>>} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {200} at {X$6323491[0],X$6323491[20/99],X$6323491[40/99],X$6323491[20/33],X$6323491[80/99],X$6323491[100/99],X$6323491[40/33],X$6323491[140/99],X$6323491[160/99],X$6323491[20/11],X$6323491[200/99],X$6323491[20/9],X$6323491[80/33],X$6323491[260/99],X$6323491[280/99],X$6323491[100/33],X$6323491[320/99],<<17>>,X$6323491[680/99],X$6323491[700/99],X$6323491[80/11],X$6323491[740/99],X$6323491[760/99],X$6323491[260/33],X$6323491[800/99],X$6323491[820/99],X$6323491[280/33],X$6323491[860/99],X$6323491[80/9],X$6323491[100/11],X$6323491[920/99],X$6323491[940/99],X$6323491[320/33],X$6323491[980/99],<<150>>} = {1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,<<150>>}. >>
```

I'm pretty sure that the problem is because of the NIntegrate... I already try to do Hold and then ReleaseHold in different parts of the @xzczd code but it's not working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `pdetoode`/`pdetoae` has made use of `Listable` attribute, which almost all the arithmetic functions own. So you just need to make your `nColdr` `Listable`. A simple example:

```
nColdr[x_?NumberQ] := NIntegrate[y^2, {y, 0, x}]

SetAttributes[nColdr, Listable]

eq = R*X''[R] - X'[R] + R^3 nColdr[R] == 0;

bc = {X[0] == 0, X[1] == 1};

domain = {0, 1};
points = 25;
grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
difforder = 4;
ptoafunc = pdetoae[X[R], grid, difforder];

ae = Delete[ptoafunc[eq], {{1}, {-1}}];

data = FindRoot[{ae, bc}, {X@#, 0} & /@ grid][[All, -1]];

pic = ListLinePlot[data, DataRange -> domain];

eqref = R*X''[R] - X'[R] + R^3 Integrate[y^2, {y, 0, R}] == 0;
sol = NDSolveValue[{eqref, bc /. X[0] -> X[10^-6]}, X, {R, 10^-6, 1}];
ListLinePlot[sol, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed, Thick}]~Show~pic
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you! Let me just ask the following: I thought that the variable 'difforder' was supposed to indicate the order of the differential equation, but now I see I was completely wrong since you set it to 4. What is then the meaning of it?

Comment: @AJHC It means "difference order" i.e. the order of difference formula being chosen. (Perhaps I should not use this abbreviation any more from now on… )

Comment: It's okay I think... the problem is mine because I couldn't understand the pdetoode code. Anyway, as higher the difference order the higher the precision right?

Comment: @AJHC Nope, this is a rather complicated topic actually. Some discussion can be found in `tutorial/NDSolvePDE` of the document. A rule of thumb is, `4` or `2` will work for most cases, and "Try it out" is the only way to figure out the best suited difference order in practice.

Comment: Maybe the tutorial you are refering to is tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines instead?

Comment: @AJHC Oh, I forgot its name has changed after _v10_. Anyway, I'm referring to the tutorial that involves introduction for ``NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative``.

Comment: I can see in the tutorial that for each difference order there are, at least, three different formulas for $f'$ and $f''$. Is it possible to know which one Mathematica is using?

Comment: @AJHC ``NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative`` uses one-sided difference formula at and near the boundary, and central difference formula in the middle, or it won't be able to generate enough equations for the whole domain. You can use `pdetoae` to discretize a single `X'[R]` and observe the output. If you're not familiar with one-sided formula, start from page 6 of [this book](https://disciplinas.stoa.usp.br/pluginfile.php/41896/mod_resource/content/1/LeVeque%20Finite%20Diff.pdf).

Comment: I'm now trying to use pdetoae with the BCs X'[0]==X[0] and I also tried X'[0]==0 but in both cases I get the error
        `The function value etc etc is not a list of numbers with dimensions...`

Isn't it possible to use pdetoae with Neuman-type BCs?

Comment: @ajhc Yes, just try it out.

Comment: For example, using exactly the same code of your answer, but using X'[0]==0 instead of X[0]==0 shouts the error `The function value (...) is not a list of numbers with dimensions {25} at (...)`

Comment: @AJHC That's because the b.c.s in your question are Dirichlet b.c.s so there's no need to use `pdetoae` on them and I did not. Now you just need to use `pdetoae` on your b.c., try it out.

Comment: you're right. I changed the condition X'[0]==X[0] from a BC to an equation which made me stay with only one BC. Then I had 10+1 algebraic equations, where the first one from the group of 10 and the new one were incompatible, and so I deleted the first one from the group of 10. However, I still had to delete one more equation from the group of 10 and I chose it randomly... Is that ok?

Comment: @ajhc …Discretization of `X'[0]==X[0]` doesn't need to be that troublesome, try `ptoafunc[X'[0]==X[0]]`.

Comment: Yes, that gives the same thing with less effort ;) my question is: when deleting 2 of the equations, one of them I delete because it's incompaible with the equation that results from ptoafunc[X'[0]==X[0]]. What about the other one? I can chose it randomly?

Comment: @ajhc It depends on the position of the other boundary condition, _usually_ the difference equations that are the closest ones to the b.c. are to be removed. If it's e.g. `X[0]==…` then `ae = Delete[ptoafunc[eq], {{1}, {2}}];`, if it's e.g. `X[1]==…` then `ae = Delete[ptoafunc[eq], {{1}, {-1}}];`. Your next question is probably "why I should remove difference equation in this way?" Well, to be honest, I don't know, this is somewhat a empirical rule to me.