# How to resolve the fail when applying a user-defined solver?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, programming

The user-defined function `pdetoode` and `pdetoae`, developed by @xzczd, is very useful to deal with a PDE system when there is difficult to discretize it into a system of ODEs. In this situation, `NDSolve` often transforms it into a DAE system and then uses a DAE solver, which is weaker than ODE solver. That is why it normally failed in such a case.

Here I tried to use `pdetoae` to solve such a PDE system with random initial conditions. Then I want to use the solutions to solve for another equation further by calling the previous solutions somehow. Please find the function `pdetoode` and `pdetoae` at [this link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127980/dynamic-euler-bernoulli-beam-equation/127997#127997).

```
Clear[f, m, Tend];
f[y_] := y; m = 300; Tend = 10;

(*Ramdom Iintial Conditions*)
Clear[a0, b0, c0, d0]    
SeedRandom[1];
a0 = Interpolation[
   Table[{(-20 + i)/20, If[1 <= i < 40, RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 0]}, {i, 
     0, 40}], InterpolationOrder -> 4];
SeedRandom[2];
b0 = Interpolation[
   Table[{(-20 + i)/20, If[1 <= i < 40, RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 0]}, {i, 
     0, 40}], InterpolationOrder -> 4];
SeedRandom[3];
c0 = Interpolation[
   Table[{(-20 + i)/20, If[1 <= i < 40, RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 0]}, {i, 
     0, 40}], InterpolationOrder -> 4];
SeedRandom[4];
d0 = Interpolation[
   Table[{(-20 + i)/20, If[1 <= i < 40, RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 0]}, {i, 
     0, 40}], InterpolationOrder -> 4];

Clear[difforder, domain, points, grid];

difforder = 4; 
domain[y] = {-1, 1}; domain[t] = {0, Tend};
points[y] = 201; points[t] = 101;
(grid@# = Array[# &, points@#, domain@#]) & /@ {y, t};

Clear[a, b, c, d];
With[{a = a[t, y], b = b[t, y], c = c[t, y], d = d[t, y]},
  eq = {I*a + D[b, y] + I*c == 0,
    D[a, t] + I*f[y]*a + b*D[f[y], y] + I*d == 
     1/m*(D[a, {y, 2}] - 2*a),
    D[b, t] + I*f[y]*b + D[d, y] == 1/m*(D[b, {y, 2}] - 2*b),
    D[c, t] + I*f[y]*c + I*d == 1/m*(D[c, {y, 2}] - 2*c)};
  ic = {a == a0[y], b == b0[y], c == c0[y], d == d0[y]} /. t -> 0;
  bc = {{a == 0, b == 0, c == 0, d == 0} /. 
     y -> -1, {a == 0, b == 0, c == 0, d == 0} /. y -> 1};];
ptoafunc = pdetoae[{a, b, c, d}[t, y], grid /@ {t, y}, difforder];
del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &; 
ae = Map[del, Most /@ ptoafunc[eq], {2}];
aeic = Map[del, ptoafunc[ic]];
aebc = ptoafunc@bc;
var = Outer[#[#2, #3] &, {a, b, c, d}, grid[t], grid[y]];
{barray, marray} = 
  CoefficientArrays[Flatten[{ae, aeic, aebc}], Flatten[var]];
sollst = LinearSolve[marray, -barray];
solmatlst = ArrayReshape[sollst, var // Dimensions];
solfunclst = ListInterpolation[#, grid /@ {t, y}] & /@ solmatlst;
```

**Update:**

`pdetoae` can solve this system, however, the solution obtained is totally noisy, like the following figure. Also I found if using `ic = {a == a0[y], b == b0[y], c == c0[y], d == d0[y]} /. t -> Tend`, that is, using `Tend` as the initial time, the solution seems reasonable.

[image]

I am quite sure that the problem stems from some mistakes in the removal of boundary difference equations for implementation of BCs/ICs instead of using higher difference order. According to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174772/using-nintegrate-in-finite-difference-derivative-method/174775#174775), I understood that: the b.c.s of the problem are Dirichlet type so there's no need to use `pdetoae` on them, as did in the code.

Some specific questions:

1. In `ae = Map[del, Most /@ ptoafunc[eq], {2}]`, why we should apply `del` to each element on the 2nd level in *list* `fptoafunc[feq]` with its last element removed (by `Most[list]`)?
2. How to store the solution, which can then be used to solve for another equation? For example,

`NDSolve[{D[u[t, y], t] - 1/m*D[u[t, y], {y, 2}] == -2*Real[b[t, y]*Conjugate[D[a[t, y], y]] + I*Conjugate[c[t, y]]*a[t, y]], u[0, y] == 0, u[t, -1] == 0, u[t, 1] == 0}, u, {t, 0, Tend}, {y, -1, 1}]`

in which the solution `a[t,y]`, `b[t, y]` and `c[t, y]` should be used to compute the RHS of the diffusion equation.

Could anybody help me? Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: 1. Please read this comment carefully: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174772/using-nintegrate-in-finite-difference-derivative-method/174775#comment464510_174775 Notice `pdetoae` is merely auxiliary function for the implementation of FDM, you must first understand the basic of FDM before using `pdetoae`.  2. "I didn't want to use Dumpsave since it normally is used to save the full info. " What do you mean by "full info"?

Comment: @xzczd 1. already read all the comments again and again but cannot figure out mistakes. I don't understand `Most /@ ptoafunc[eq]` although I knew the basic FDM. 2. By ''full info.'' I meant all data of an `InterpolationFunction`, including mesh, all the derivative values, etc. Here, only the time evolution of the original functions and the first space-derivatives are needed. If my understanding is wrong, please kindly suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Think about how to solve $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2},u(0,x)=x(1-x),u(t,0)=u(t,1)=0$ with `pdetoae` first. 2. Your guess for `InterpolatingFunction` is wrong. Just check `Interpolation[{1, 3, 6, 4, 5}] // InputForm`. Also, check [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28337/1871).

Comment: @xzczd To solve the diffusion eq, one may use centered diff in space and forward diff in time: $u_i^{n+1}=u_i^n+dt/dx^2 (u_{i-1}^n-2u_i^n+u_{i+1}^n)$. Since it is an explicit method, having nothing to do with `LinearSolve`, I guess we should use an implicit method to employing `pdetoae`, e.g. CN scheme. Am I right?

Comment: @xzczd I found in my trial if using `ae = Map[del, Rest /@ ptoafunc[eq], {2}];` my code give a reasonable soln. It removed the first difference equation from `ptoafunc[eq]` by `Rest`.

Comment: "Since it is an explicit method, having nothing to do with `LinearSolve`. " No, even if it's an explicit scheme, one can still write down every equation and solve the whole system all in once with `LinearSolve`. Yes, the answer for your question is replace `Most` with `Rest`, now tell me why.

Comment: @xzczd 1. Yes, you are right. In the explicit method, these equations are merely independent. 2. I just knew the usage of `Most` and `Rest`. I think it depends on the position of the equation for ic.

Comment: That's it, and now you can answer the question yourself.

Comment: @xzczd thanks for guiding me. However, the second question is not resolved...

Comment: As I've already mentioned, `InterpolatingFunction` isn't as expensive as you've imagined. Store it with `DumpSave` is the proper way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All issues are resolved by @xzczd. I will publish the solution to the problem so that the topic is completed

```
Clear[fdd, pdetoode, tooderule]
fdd[{}, grid_, value_, order_, periodic_] := value;
fdd[a__] := NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative@a;

pdetoode[funcvalue_List, rest__] := 
  pdetoode[(Alternatives @@ Head /@ funcvalue) @@ funcvalue[[1]], 
   rest];
pdetoode[{func__}[var__], rest__] := 
  pdetoode[Alternatives[func][var], rest];
pdetoode[front__, grid_?VectorQ, o_Integer, periodic_: False] := 
  pdetoode[front, {grid}, o, periodic];

pdetoode[func_[var__], time_, {grid : {__} ..}, o_Integer, 
   periodic : True | False | {(True | False) ..} : False] := 
  With[{pos = Position[{var}, time][[1, 1]]}, 
   With[{bound = #[[{1, -1}]] & /@ {grid}, 
     pat = Repeated[_, {pos - 1}], 
     spacevar = Alternatives @@ Delete[{var}, pos]}, 
    With[{coordtoindex = 
       Function[coord, 
        MapThread[
         Piecewise[{{1, # === #2[[1]]}, {-1, # === #2[[-1]]}}, 
           All] &, {coord, bound}]]}, 
     tooderule@
      Flatten@{((u : func) | 
            Derivative[dx1 : pat, dt_, dx2___][(u : func)])[x1 : pat, 
          t_, x2___] :> (Sow@coordtoindex@{x1, x2};

          fdd[{dx1, dx2}, {grid}, 
           Outer[Derivative[dt][u@##]@t &, grid], 
           "DifferenceOrder" -> o, 
           PeriodicInterpolation -> periodic]), 
        inde : spacevar :> 
         With[{i = Position[spacevar, inde][[1, 1]]}, 
          Outer[Slot@i &, grid]]}]]];

tooderule[rule_][pde_List] := tooderule[rule] /@ pde;
tooderule[rule_]@Equal[a_, b_] := 
  Equal[tooderule[rule][a - b], 0] //. 
   eqn : HoldPattern@Equal[_, _] :> Thread@eqn;
tooderule[rule_][expr_] := #[[Sequence @@ #2[[1, 1]]]] & @@ 
  Reap[expr /. rule]

Clear@pdetoae;
pdetoae[funcvalue_List, rest__] := 
  pdetoae[(Alternatives @@ Head /@ funcvalue) @@ funcvalue[[1]], rest];
pdetoae[{func__}[var__], rest__] := 
  pdetoae[Alternatives[func][var], rest];

pdetoae[func_[var__], rest__] := 
 Module[{t}, 
  Function[pde, #[
       pde /. {Derivative[d__][u : func][inde__] :> 
          Derivative[d, 0][u][inde, t], (u : func)[inde__] :> 
          u[inde, t]}] /. (u : func)[i__][t] :> u[i]] &@
   pdetoode[func[var, t], t, rest]]

Clear[f, m, Tend];
f[y_] := y; m = 300; Tend = 10;

(*Ramdom Iintial Conditions*)
Clear[a0, b0, c0, d0]

SeedRandom[1];
a0 = Interpolation[
   Table[{(-20 + i)/20, If[1 <= i < 40, RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 0]}, {i, 
     0, 40}], InterpolationOrder -> 4];
SeedRandom[2];
b0 = Interpolation[
   Table[{(-20 + i)/20, If[1 <= i < 40, RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 0]}, {i, 
     0, 40}], InterpolationOrder -> 4];
SeedRandom[3];
c0 = Interpolation[
   Table[{(-20 + i)/20, If[1 <= i < 40, RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 0]}, {i, 
     0, 40}], InterpolationOrder -> 4];
SeedRandom[4];
d0 = Interpolation[
   Table[{(-20 + i)/20, If[1 <= i < 40, RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 0]}, {i, 
     0, 40}], InterpolationOrder -> 4];

Clear[difforder, domain, points, grid];

difforder = 4;
domain[y] = {-1, 1}; domain[t] = {0, Tend};
points[y] = 201; points[t] = 101;
(grid@# = Array[# &, points@#, domain@#]) & /@ {y, t};

Clear[a, b, c, d];
With[{a = a[t, y], b = b[t, y], c = c[t, y], d = d[t, y]}, 
  eq = {I*a + D[b, y] + I*c == 0, 
    D[a, t] + I*f[y]*a + b*D[f[y], y] + I*d == 
     1/m*(D[a, {y, 2}] - 2*a), 
    D[b, t] + I*f[y]*b + D[d, y] == 1/m*(D[b, {y, 2}] - 2*b), 
    D[c, t] + I*f[y]*c + I*d == 1/m*(D[c, {y, 2}] - 2*c)};
  ic = {a == a0[y], b == b0[y], c == c0[y], d == d0[y]} /. t -> 0;
  bc = {{a == 0, b == 0, c == 0, d == 0} /. 
     y -> -1, {a == 0, b == 0, c == 0, d == 0} /. y -> 1};];
ptoafunc = pdetoae[{a, b, c, d}[t, y], grid /@ {t, y}, difforder];
del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
ae = Map[del, Rest /@ ptoafunc[eq], {2}];
aeic = Map[del, ptoafunc[ic]];
aebc = ptoafunc@bc;
var = Outer[#[#2, #3] &, {a, b, c, d}, grid[t], grid[y]];
{barray, marray} = 
  CoefficientArrays[Flatten[{ae, aeic, aebc}], Flatten[var]];
sollst = LinearSolve[marray, -barray];
solmatlst = ArrayReshape[sollst, var // Dimensions];


solfunclst = ListInterpolation[#, grid /@ {t, y}] & /@ solmatlst

sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, y], t] - 1/m*D[u[t, y], {y, 2}] == -2*
     Re[solfunclst[[2]][t, y]*
        Conjugate[Derivative[0, 1][solfunclst[[1]]][t, y]] + 
       I*Conjugate[solfunclst[[3]][t, y]]*solfunclst[[1]][t, y]], 
   u[0, y] == 0, u[t, -1] == 0, u[t, 1] == 0}, 
  u, {t, 0, Tend}, {y, -1, 1}];
p = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};

{Table[Plot[ReIm@solfunclst[[i]][10, y], {y, -1, 1}, 
   PlotLabel -> p[[i]]], {i, 4}], 
 Plot3D[sol[t, y], {t, 0, Tend}, {y, -1, 1}, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, AxesLabel -> {"t", "y", "u"}]}
```

[image: fig1]