# Error using pdetoode

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve the system of equations:

```
eq1 = (Exp[-2 λ[t, r]] D[R[t, r], r]^2)/R[t, r]^2 - 
   2 (Exp[-2 λ[t, r]] D[R[t, r], r] D[λ[t, r], r])/
    R[t, r] + 
   2 (Exp[-2 λ[t, r]] D[R[t, r], {r, 2}])/R[t, r] - (
   Exp[-2 ν[t, r]] D[R[t, r], t]^2)/R[t, r] - 
   2 (Exp[-2 ν[t, r]] D[R[t, r], t] D[ν[t, r], t])/R[t, r] + (
    8 Pi G)/3 ϵ[t, r];

eq3 = (Exp[-2 λ[t, r]] D[R[t, r], r]^2)/R[t, r]^2 + 
   2 (Exp[-2 λ[t, r]] D[R[t, r], r] D[ν[t, r], r])/
    R[t, r] - (Exp[-2 ν[t, r]] D[R[t, r], t]^2)/R[t, r]^2 + 
   2 (Exp[-2 ν[t, r]] D[R[t, r], t] D[ν[t, r], t])/R[t, r] - 
   2 (Exp[-2 ν[t, r]] D[R[t, r], {t, 2}])/R[t, r] - (8 Pi G)/
    3 ϵ[t, r]/3;
```

where the functions $\epsilon$ and $\nu$ are given by:

```
ϵ[t_, r_]=(E^( - 4/3 λ[t, r]) (1/100)^(8/3))/R[t, r]^(8/3)
ν[t_, r_]=1/4 (Log[1/(1 + t)^(8/3)] - Log[E^(-(4/3) λ[t, r])/R[t, r]^(8/3)])
```

I use the method `pdetoode` by @xzczd as follows:

```
lb = 10^-1;
rb = 1;
xdifforder1 = 2;
xdifforder2 = 1;
ic1 = {R[0, r] == 10^-2, Derivative[1, 0][R][0, r] == 1};
ic2 = {λ[0, r] == 0};
bc1 = {R[t, 0] == t + 10^-2, R[t, 10^-1] == 10^-2, 
   Derivative[0, 1][R][t, 0] == 0};
bc2 = {λ[t, 0] == 0};
points = 25;
grid = Array[# &, points, {lb, rb}];
removeredundant1 = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
removeredundant2 = #[[1 ;; -1]] &;
ptoofunc1 = pdetoode[R[t, r], t, grid, xdifforder1];
ptoofunc2 = pdetoode[λ[t, r], t, grid, xdifforder2];
odeqn1 = eq1 // ptoofunc1 // removeredundant1;
odeqn2 = eq3 // ptoofunc2 // removeredundant2;
odeic1 = removeredundant1 /@ ptoofunc1@ic1;
odeic2 = removeredundant2 /@ ptoofunc2@ic2;
odebc1 = bc1 // ptoofunc1;
odebc2 = bc2 // ptoofunc2;
sollst = NDSolveValue[{odebc1, odebc2, odeic1, odeic2, odeqn1, odeqn2}, {R /@ grid, [Lambda] /@ grid}, {t, 0, 1},  MaxSteps -> Infinity]
sol = rebuild[sollst, grid]
```

but I get the error:

[image]

So it seems that while it works well for $R$, the grid points are not mapped onto $\lambda$ and it becomes a function of a list. I do not understand why it happens, since it seems to me that I am applying the same method to both $R$ and $\lambda$. Can anyone help?

**EDIT**

After the comment by @xzczd, my code now looks like this:

```
lb = 10^-1;
rb = 1;
xdifforder = 4;
ic = {R[0, r] == 10^-2, 
   Derivative[1, 0][R][0, r] == 1, λ[0, r] == 0};
bc = {R[t, 0] == t + 10^-2, R[t, 10^-1] == 10^-2, 
   Derivative[0, 1][R][t, 0] == 0, λ[t, 0] == 0};
points = 25;
grid = Array[# &, points, {lb, rb}];
removeredundant = #[[3 ;; -3]] &;
ptoofunc = pdetoode[{R[t, r], λ[t, r]}, t, grid, xdifforder];
odeqn1 = eq1 // ptoofunc // removeredundant;
odeqn2 = eq3 // ptoofunc // removeredundant;
odeic = removeredundant /@ ptoofunc@ic;
odebc = bc // ptoofunc;
```

but now Mathematica complaints that there are fewer variables than equations

Comment: Why do you use `pdetoode` twice?

Comment: @xzczd because I have two functions $R$ and $\lambda$, I have found some posts on this site for system of equations and, as far as I understand, this seems to be the method. Is it wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's wrong. If the domain of the unknown functions are the same, then you only need to use `pdetoode` once, i.e. `pdetoode[{R[t, r], \[Lambda][t, r]}, …` or simply `pdetoode[{R, \[Lambda]}[t, r], …`

Comment: @xzczd but the functions have different differentiation order: $R$ it is 2, while $\lambda$ it is 1

Comment: `diff` is short for differen**ce**. You may want to read the comments here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/174775/1871

Comment: @xzczd Sorry to bother again, but the code still does not work, now I get the error `There are fewer variables than equations`.

Comment: You haven't _make room_ for the b.c.s in the correct way. Please read the comments in the link of my last comment carefully.

Comment: @xzczd I am sorry but I do not understand, can you show me that line of code?

Comment: 1. Why do you define `removeredundant = #[[3 ;; -3]] &;`? 2. the highest differential order of $R$ in $r$ direction is `2`, are you sure you need `3` b.c.s for $R$? 3. `lb=0.1` while two of the b.c.s are `R[t, 0] == t + 10^-2, Derivative[0, 1][R][t, 0] == 0`?

Comment: @xzczd 1) because I have 3 boundary conditions on $R$. 2,3) those are mistakes, thanks for pointing them out. How should I define `removeredundant`?

Comment: Observe the output of `removeredundant@{a, b, c, d, e, f, g}` and think about what's wrong. For more info, check the document of `Part` (`[[]]`) and `Span` (`;;`) carefully.

Comment: @xzczd ok so `[[3;;-1]]` keeps all the elements from the third onward. I have 3 bc so I should write `removeredundant = #[[4 ;; -1]] &;`, but now there are more variables than equations...

Comment: You have 3 b.c.s, then how many equations should you remove from `eq1 // ptoofunc` **and**  `eq3 // ptoofunc`?

Comment: @xzczd Ok now I understand. Thanks and sorry for the long discussion

Comment: That's all right. But I'm afraid the really troublesome part has just begun. Your equation system looks unusual, is it something related to general relativity? If `NDSolve` fails in the next step, I'd suggest: 1. Double-check if the system itself is correct. 2. First try reproducing some well-validated results in the field with `NDSolve` to make sure `NDSolve` is capable of solving such type of problem.

Comment: @xzczd Yes they are Einstein equations for a spherical symmetric metric. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

This system can be solved with DAE solver on the short time interval `{t,0,.08}` as follows

```
ϵ = (Exp[(-4/3 λ[t, r])] (1/100)^(8/3))/R[t, r]^(8/3);
ν = 1/
    4 (Log[1/(1 + t)^(8/3)] - 
     Log[E^(-(4/3) λ[t, r])/R[t, r]^(8/3)]);

eq = {(Exp[-2 λ[t, r]] D[R[t, r], r]^2)/R[t, r]^2 - 
    2 (Exp[-2 λ[t, r]] D[R[t, r], r] D[λ[t, r], r])/
      R[t, r] + 
    2 (Exp[-2 λ[t, r]] D[R[t, r], {r, 2}])/
      R[t, r] - (Exp[-2 ν] D[R[t, r], t]^2)/R[t, r] - 
    2 (Exp[-2 ν] D[R[t, r], t] D[ν, t])/R[t, r] + (8 Pi G)/
      3 ϵ,
   (Exp[-2 λ[t, r]] D[R[t, r], r]^2)/R[t, r]^2 + 
    2 (Exp[-2 λ[t, r]] D[R[t, r], r] D[ν, r])/
      R[t, r] - (Exp[-2 ν] D[R[t, r], t]^2)/R[t, r]^2 + 
    2 (Exp[-2 ν] D[R[t, r], t] D[ν, t])/R[t, r] - 
    2 (Exp[-2 ν] D[R[t, r], {t, 2}])/R[t, r] - (8 Pi G)/
      3 ϵ/3} // Simplify

ic = {R[t, r] == 10^-2, D[R[t, r], t] == 1, λ[t, r] == 0} /. 
   t -> 0;
bc = {R[t, r] - t - 10^-2 == 0, 
    D[R[t, r], r] == 0, λ[t, r] == 0} /. r -> lb;


G = 1; lb = 10^-1;
rb = 1;
sol = NDSolve[{eq[[1]]+eq[[2]] == 0, eq[[2]] == 0, ic, 
   bc}, {R, λ}, {t, 0, .08}, {r, lb, rb}, 
  Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic, 
    "EquationSimplification" -> "Residual", 
    "PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
        "MinPoints" -> 80, "MaxPoints" -> 80, 
        "DifferenceOrder" -> 8}}}]

{Plot3D[Evaluate[R[t, r] /. sol[[1]]], {t, 0, 0.08}, {r, lb, rb}, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, Mesh -> None, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, PlotPoints -> 50], 
 Plot3D[Evaluate[λ[t, r] /. sol[[1]]], {t, 0, 0.08}, {r, lb, 
   rb}, ColorFunction -> Hue, Mesh -> None, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
  Boxed -> False, PlotPoints -> 50]}
```

It looks very regular, but it is not clear why system blow up after `t=0.089`
[image: Figure 2]

There is a stable solution for $\lambda >0$ with the set of boundary conditions

```
ic = {R[t, r] == 10^-2, 
    D[R[t, r], t] == 1/100, λ[t, r] == 0} /. t -> 0;
bc = {R[t, r] - t/100 - 10^-2 == 0, 
    D[R[t, r], r] == 0, λ[t, r] == 0} /. r -> lb;
```

This solution on `{t,0,1}` looks like

[image: Figure 2]

Note, we are not been able to reproduce any of these results with using `pdetoode` or `pdetoae`.