# Why does NDSolve blow up when given my ODE but bvp4c in Matlab does not?

Tags: differential-equations, matlab, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I am numerically solving the following ODE initially using NDSolve in Mathematica(updated and corrected):

$-(-\frac{z'(r)}{r \sqrt{z'(r)^2+1}}-\frac{z''(r)}{\left(z'(r)^2+1\right)^{3/2}})=A_1(z(r)+H)+A_2(\frac{A_3}{\sqrt{z(r)^2+r^2}-1})^3$

subject to boundary conditions of $z'(0) = 0$, and $z(\infty) = - H$. In this case, $r = 4$ or even 1 can be treated as infinity.

The left-hand-side is twice the mean curvature of a surface of revolution characterized by $z(r)$ in cylindrical coordinates. Parameters $A_1, A_2, A_3$ and $H$ are provided. I anticipated a solution that looked like this:

[image]

The expected solution (blue curve) is perturbed by the presence of the sphere near $r = 0$ and resumes its unperturbed shape (a straight line) at $r = \infty$. Note that H is the vertical distance of z(r) to the line of $z = 0$ at $r = \infty$..

The Mathematica code used:

```
A1 = 200;
A2 = 1.86*10^7;
A3 = 0.0002;
H=1;
f[z_, r_] := A1 (z + H) + A2 (A3/(Sqrt[z^2 + r^2]-1))^3;
k := -(z''[r]/(z'[r]^2 + 1)^(3/2)) - If[r == 0, 0, z'[r]/(r Sqrt[z'[r]^2 +1])]);
sol = NDSolve[{-k == f[z[r], r], z'[0] == 0, z[1] == -H}, z, {r, 0, 1}];
```

However, `NDSolve` was not able to yield sensible results,  with $z(r)$ either blowing up to $z  = \infty$ or simply "encountered stiffness", even if variations of the boundary conditions were attempted, i.e.

1) `z'[0.0001] = 0, z[0.0001] = -1.01`

2) `z'[1] = 0, z[1] = - H`

3) `z'[0.0001 = 0, z[1] = -H`

To my surprise, Matlab on the other hand handled the identical system well using bvp4c (4th order RK method) without blow-up, and yielded the solution shown in the figure above.

Any clue as to why Mathematica resulted in a blow-up solution yet Matlab converged well? Any explanations will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show your Matlab code also?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to StackExchange, how do I send you my Matlab code?

Comment: You should be able to paste it here I would think.

Comment: clc
xlow=1e-10; xhigh=2;
solinit = bvpinit(linspace(xlow,xhigh,20),[-1.03 0]); 
sol = bvp4c(@twoode,@twobc,solinit);
xint = linspace(xlow,xhigh);
Sxint = deval(sol,xint);
plot(xint,Sxint(1,:),xint,-(1-xint.^2).^0.5)
pbaspect([1 1 1])
xlabel('r')
ylabel('z')

%% ---
function dydx = twoode(x,y)
A0=5.36e-14;
Lambda=2.0e-10;
G=1.0e4;
R=1.0e-6;
Tm=933;
H=1e-6;
A1=G*R^2/A0/Tm;
A2=G*H*R/A0/Tm;
A3=R/A0;
A4=Lambda/R;
% A1=0;
% A2=0;
% A3=0;
% A4=0;
zpp=(A1*y(1)+A2+A3*(A4/(sqrt(y(1)^2+x^2)-1))^3)*(1+y(2)^2)^1.5-y(2)*(1+y(2)^2)/x;
%zpp=-abs(y(1));
dydx = [ y(2) zpp ];
end

Comment: %% ---------------This is the second half------------------------
function res = twobc(ya,yb)
H=1e-6;
R=1.0e-6;
res = [ ya(2) yb(1)+H/R];
end

Answer (score 16):

First, there is a mistake in the sign `k`. And secondly, for such tasks we use a special method that expands the possibilities of the shooting method. I will demonstrate the working code

```
A1 = 200;
A2 = 186*10^5;
A3 = 1/5000;
a = Rationalize[A2*A3^3];
H = 1; r0 = 10^-5;
f[z_, r_] := A1*(z + H) + a*(1/(Sqrt[z^2 + r^2] - 1))^3;
k = -z''[r]/(z'[r]^2 + 1)^(3/2) - z'[r]/(r Sqrt[z'[r]^2 + 1]);
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{k == f[z[r], r], z'[r0] == 0, 
    z[r0] == z0}, z, {r, r0, 1}, {z0}];
Plot[Evaluate[Table[sol[z0][r], {z0, -1.15, -1.05, .01}]], {r, r0, 1},
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: fig1]

Find the parameter that satisfies the boundary condition on the right border

```
FindRoot[sol[z0][1] == -H, {z0, -1.05}]

Out[]= {z0 -> -1.03176}
{Plot[sol[-1.03176][r], {r, r0, 1}],Plot[{sol[-1.03176][r], -Sqrt[1 - r^2]}, {r, r0, 1}]}
```

[image: fig2]

The author insists that the correct model corresponds to his code. We give a solution for this case. The solution method does not change.

```
A1 = 200;
A2 = 186*10^5;
A3 = 1/5000;
a = Rationalize[A2*A3^3];
H = 1; r0 = 10^-5;
f[z_, r_] := A1*(z + H) + a*(1/(Sqrt[z^2 + r^2] - 1))^3;
k = z''[r]/(z'[r]^2 + 1)^(3/2) + z'[r]/(r Sqrt[z'[r]^2 + 1]);
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{k == f[z[r], r], z'[1] == z1, 
    z[1] == -H}, z, {r, r0, 1}, {z1}, WorkingPrecision -> 30];
{Plot[Evaluate[
    Table[sol[z1][
      r], {z1, .00024816068, .00024816069, .000000000001}]], {r, r0, 
    1}, PlotRange -> All], 
  Plot[Evaluate[
    Table[sol[z1][
      r], {z1, .00024816068, .00024816069, .000000000001}]], {r, 
    r0, .01}, PlotRange -> All]} // Quiet
```

[image: fig3]

Comment: Thanks Alex. I have double-checked the literature that the sign of k in my original post is correct, it is indeed -k = f (z(r) ,r ), and the signs for z'' and z' in the expression of k are both negative, but the wavy behavior in your post is not expected in the actual solution.

What advantage does ParametricNDSolveValue have over just NDSolve? I see that NDSolve could equally handle well  k = f (z,r), and neither of them can solve 
- k = f(z,r)  without blowing up.

Comment: Maybe you should check three times. Look at the original equation  https://i.stack.imgur.com/yP3xE.gif and your code. What solution do you expect to get?

Comment: Opps you are correct, the expression in the image is incorrect. The expression in the code is what I am supposed to solve, and is what lead to blow-up issue.

Comment: Are you kidding? Give a link to the article or book where you took this equation.

Comment: The equation I took is from this link. [link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021999116300092) Eqn 47 and 48, the definitions of parameters are given directly below Eqn 48, but you may use the values I provided initially. The solution z(r) is shown in Fig 3 (b) via 4th order RK method. I can provide a PDF copy if you don't have access to Journal of Computational Physics. Thanks!

Comment: Notice that your solution https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pnQ8.png received on Matlab and my solution https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jn5uP.png is similar to the solution shown in FIG. 3 in Article https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021999116300092

Comment: They do appear quite similar but if you look closely, the wavy nature of your solution is not present in the Matlab solution or in that paper.

Comment: The solution of the equation in FIG. 3 represents a thick line with markers. There you will not see the waves, even if they are.

Comment: The second case with -k, I also reviewed and found a solution

Comment: Thanks a bunch Alex, it seemed that there existed a singularity point as suggested by the second answer. Whether or not the solution leads to blow-up strongly depends on the initial guess. I am curious as to how you picked your z1 with that many decimal points, z1= .00024816068

Comment: @Linmin I have a code that allows us to search for such points.

Comment: Would it be possible if you could send it to me? I'm new to this forum and don't know how sending files is done.

Comment: @Linmin I will publish the code as soon as I can and give a link.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 5):

This type of problem has been discussed in this site for many times, for example [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/174045/1871), and you can find more by searching [`Shooting`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdifferential-equations%5Dshooting) in this site. For completness I'd like to add a solution based on finite difference method (FDM). I'll use [`pdetoae`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for the task:

```
A1 = 200;
A2 = 186/100 10^7;
A3 = 2 10^-4;
H = 1;
f[z_, r_] = A1 (z + H) + A2 (A3/(Sqrt[z^2 + r^2] - 1))^3;
k = -(z''[r]/(z'[r]^2 + 1)^(3/2)) - z'[r]/(r Sqrt[z'[r]^2 + 1]);

{eq, bc} = {-k == f[z[r], r], {z'[0] == 0, z[1] == -H}};

(* Remove the removable singularity *)
neweq = 0 == (Together[Subtract @@ eq] // Numerator);

points = 25; domain = {0, 1}; grid = Array[# &, points, domain]; difforder = 4;
(* Definition of pdetoae isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoafunc = pdetoae[z[r], grid, difforder];
del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
ae = ptoafunc@neweq // del;
aebc = ptoafunc@bc;
initial[r_] = -1;
sollst = FindRoot[{ae, aebc}, Table[{z[r], initial@r}, {r, grid}], 
   WorkingPrecision -> 16][[All, -1]]
sol = ListInterpolation[sollst, grid]

Plot[sol[r], {r, 0, H}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks very much, I will be reading those posts about shooting method for this peculiar ODE system.

I also noticed that you and the first answer rationalized all parameters even if I originally assigned 0.0002 to A3, which seemed counterintuitive to me since my common sense told me that float-point numbers would speed up numerical calculations. Any reason why?

Comment: @Linmin High level numeric functions like `FindRoot`, `NDSolve` automatically turns to float-point numbers by default, so you don't need to manually change the parameters to float-point number. On the other hand, using float-point number obstructs adjustion for options like `WorkingPrecision`. (Just remove this option from my code and use `A3=0.0002` and retry. ) BTW, you can also use `Rationalize[…, 0]` for rationalizing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that does help clarify some points.